# I am a word. What word am I?

Tags: riddle, word, wordplay

> I am a word.
>
> Six letters I contain.
>
> Give me a bread-maker and unlucky I became.
>
> Take one away and twelve is what will remain.
>
> Take two away and asleep I feign.
>
> Take three and Superman, I will tame.

**What word am I?**

Comment: Feedback: well-constructed riddle, but possibly too easy. I knew the answer as soon as I saw "*Give me a bread-maker and unlucky I became.*"

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You are the word

> DOZENS.

Line by line:

I am a word.
Six letters I contain.

> DOZENS is a 6-letter word.

Give me a bread-maker and unlucky I became.

> A baker's dozen is 13 loaves, and 13 has often been considered an unlucky number. (I think we're adding "baker" to "dozens" and moving the S.)

Take one away and twelve is what will remain.

> A dozen.

Take two away and asleep I feign.

> DOZE.

Take three and Superman, I will tame.

> General ZOD. (Rearranging again.)

Comment: No fair changing your answer to mine, while I’m out trying to find a less convoluted solution for the final clue :-)

Comment: I had already changed it when you posted yours :-). Sorry, though.

Comment: Ah, didn’t show to me yet :-)

Comment: @JonMarkPerry Please don't make pointless edits [just to get a badge](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/posts/61359/revisions).